# Why does macOS include a 2nd copy of clang called GCC?

Tags: macos, xcode, development, gcc

Since macOS uses Clang, you'd expect that `gcc` wouldn't be a valid command/executable, but macOS has a gcc executable that's exactly the same as clang.

```
5f42128bc6a36bf22b44d4d69e18ee6daff6178b  /usr/bin/clang
5f42128bc6a36bf22b44d4d69e18ee6daff6178b  /usr/bin/gcc
```

Is there any reason for this? It just seems to cause confusion when Clang works differently to GCC. The only reason that I can see them doing this is because most C resources assume you're using GCC.

Comment: Maybe it's just a sym-link? And, yes, it's probably for compatibility with older OSes. Which OS are you on? Checking on 10.14.6, 'gcc' and 'clang' are the same size, but different i-nums and different checksums. They are just small handlers to call the "big" commands.

Comment: Compatibility with all those scripts/Makefiles out there that assume the local C compiler is a GCC.